# Expand two Excel columns, each with multiple corresponding values

Tags: python, excel, powerquery, multivalue

How can I turn this excel table

| Country | Initiative | Staff involved | Billing hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HK | Data Lake | Amy, Ben, Li | 6,3,8 |

into this using Excel/ Python/ Power query? (not necessarily 3 staffs, can more more or less)

| Country | Initiative | Staff involved | Billing hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HK | Data Lake | Amy | 6 |
| HK | Data Lake | Ben | 3 |
| HK | Data Lake | Li | 8 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using Power Query

You could do this using Power Query from Excel by following these steps.

1. Select the data and go to Data>Get & Transform Data.
2. Select the From Sheet option, make sure My table has headers is checked and click OK.
3. In Power Query go to Add Column>Custom Column and use this for the Custom column formula.

```
= Text.Split([Staff involved], ",")
```

4. Go to Add Column>Custom Column again and use this for the formula.

```
= Text.Split([Billing Hours], ",")
```

5. Again use Add Column>Custom Column with this formula.

```
= Table.FromColumns({[Custom], [Custom.1]})
```

6. Now you can expand the last custom column to get the data you want.
7. Finally delete the unneeded columns, rename the other columns as required and go to File>Close and Load to return the data to Excel.

### M Code

Here is the full M code generated when following the above steps.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Text.Split([Staff involved], ",")),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each Text.Split([Billing hours], ",")),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom.2", each Table.FromColumns({[Custom], [Custom.1]})),
    #"Expanded Custom.2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Custom.2", {"Column1", "Column2"}, {"Custom.2.Column1", "Custom.2.Column2"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Custom.2",{"Staff involved", "Billing hours", "Custom", "Custom.1"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Custom.2.Column1", "Staff Involved"}, {"Custom.2.Column2", "Billing Hours"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

---